# How to make an automatic spawn point when you die

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

So for a map, I want to have the players re-spawn where they died so they can continue playing. I have a concept in my head that I can't quite figure out.

I was thinking of having an armor stand continue to `tp` to the player and set the spawnpoint to the armor stand, but my knowledge in this area is limited and I'm not sure how to go about this or if this would even work.  I am not stuck on this concept and am open to other ideas.

Comment: What Minecraft version are you using?

Comment: Officially using 1.9

Comment: Just to let you know, I updated my answer. You should have a better time with the newer command. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always use a command block with the following setup:

[image]

Replace `<name>` with your name, obviously.

If you want to do this with all users on a single world, use the following command:

```
/spawnpoint @a
```

Make sure you turn off command block output, though, and also make sure you put this block in a permanently loaded chunk (your spawn chunks, for example). You may wish to use a setup involving repeaters instead of a repeating command block (as repeating command blocks act very quickly, and may cause lag). I'd generally suggest against doing this, however, because you don't prevent yourself from dying in a loop (which is not only possible, but probable in this).

Comment: You should **not** be mixing `@a` as the executor with `@p` as the target. `@a` is the only selector that can target dead players, meaning if the player dies, they will set the nearest-living player's spawnpoint instead of their own. However, using `/execute` is not necessary because `/spawnpoint` alone will set the targeted player's spawnpoint to their own location. Using `/execute` here will only serve to increase the work the server needs to do.

Comment: @Skylinerw Ah - thank you. I've been using spawnpoint wrong all along. Fixing.